# How to create an executable file from python scripts for all windows?

Tags: python, exe, 32bit-64bit

How to create an executable file from python scripts?

How to create an executable file of python scripts which can be executed on windows 7 / 8/ 10 and 64 both 32 bit and 64 bit versions?

I have used PyInstaller,

but its exe gives an fatal error when I try to launch onn different windows system...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you use `pyinstaller` to create an exe file. This exe file will only run on this type of computer. For example, if you create an exe file on a windows 10 64bit, this will only work on 64 bit computers with Windows 10. So if you want to run your exe file on a windows 7 (like in your image) you need to create this exe from that computer.